# Get the position of first capital letter in a string using php

Tags: php, string, sorting

I am having array in which different letter in each word is capital like:

> aPple, Orange, baNana, mANgo, Papaya

I want to get the position of the first letter that is capital. And order them accordingly.
That is the word that has first letter capital will be first, and then with second letter capital will be second etc... Like

> Orange
>   Papaya
>   aAple
>   mAngo
>   baNana

If two words come with capital letter in same position for example in above list
Orange and Pappaya comes with first letter as capital, then they have to be sorted in alphabetic order.

Is this very hard to achieve in php?

Comment: http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could use [`strcspn()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strcspn.php)

> Find length of initial segment not matching mask

For example:

```
echo strcspn('aAple', 'ABCDEFGHJIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ');
// prints '1' - the string starts with 1 character not in upper case
```

Full Code

```
echo "<pre>" ;
$array = array("aPple", "Orange", "baNana", "mANgo", "Papaya");
foreach($array as $value)
{
    echo $value , "= " , strcspn($value, 'ABCDEFGHJIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ') . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Output

```
aPple= 1
Orange= 0
baNana= 2
mANgo= 1
Papaya= 0
```

You use that function to do your (reverse) sort.

Comment: If you dislike the idea of having the entire alphabet (for whatever reason), you can use `strcspn('aAple', implode('', range('A', 'Z')));`

Comment: @RobinCastlin Your `implode` statement saves only one character though ;-)

Comment: Yeah, that's true. But I rather let the system go A to Z then typing it myself. :D Maybe I forget a letter!

Answer (score 1):

```
preg_match("/^.*?[A-Z]/", 'aAple', $arr);

$str_position = (strlen($arr[0]) - 1);
```

There are so many ways you can do this on. Use the one you find most logical. :)

This one simply returns the first part of the string to the first Capital letter. Then I calculate string length and subtract by 1.

Answer (score 1):

If you use PHP > 5.3 you can use this:

```
$test = array("aPple", "Orange", "baNana", "mANgo", "Papaya");

echo implode(', ', array_map(function($value){
    $matches = array();
    preg_match('/[A-Z]/', $value, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
    return $matches[0][1];
}, $test));
```

Otherwise you have to create another function as replacement for the lambda function.

Output: `1, 0, 2, 1, 0`

Answer (score 1):

If you want a non-fancy way to do it , here is my suggestion :

** for gettings caps position ***

```
 function getCapsPosn($str)
 {
  $i = 0;
  $CapsPosn = -1;
  for ($i =0 ; $i < strlen($str) ; $i++)
  {
    if (( ord($str[$i]) >= 65 ) && ( ord($str[$i]) <= 90))
    {
        //echo ord($str[$i]);
        $CapsPosn = $i;
        return $CapsPosn;
    }
  }
 }
```

Use an associative array to store the Caps posn in the array .e.g. array['aPple'] = '1'
and so on. then use php sort functions to sort it. PHP sorting functions can be found at :  http://php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php